# Is it possible to cover a PC's ip when remote desktoping?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop

Let's assume we have two computers, A and B.

Computer A remote desktops to Computer B. Computer B can typically obtain Computer A's ip adress with the help of a netstat command or other ways.

Are there ANY ways of tricking/obfuscating computer A's ip? So it cannot be obtained so easily? If so, how?

Comment: No. In order for the computers to communicate, the remote host needs to know the client computer's address.  Only way around it is if you have a network that's not TCP/IP based (pretty uncommon these days.)  The remote host doesn't need to do a netstat -- it's not going to allow the connection, or be able to send anything back, without knowing the client's address.

Comment: I notice you mention ssh... was that intended? ssh has additional security. This would require what is known as a man-in-the-middle to do this. You would need to ssh to a different (proxy) box and ssh from there to hide the original.

Comment: Yes that was intended ^^. And thank you for answers.

Comment: VPN hosted somewhere whose IP you want to use instead of yours.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to remote into a separate proxy machine, and then from there remote into the one you intend to target, effectively spoofing the original ip by hiding behind the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

@jeffClayton answer is roughly correct.  Instead of using a proxy though, it would be better to use a VPN.   Of-course, presumably you still need credentials to remote into the desktop which might give the game away.

Comment: A VPN is not a type of proxy by definition as it does not "act as an intermediary for requests from clients seeking resources from other servers", rather it can change the apparent location of your traffic a side effect of its main function (encrypting traffic between 2 machines/networks not directly connected so as to make them appear as they are on the same network)   A Proxy is a device acting as "man in the middle". Because RDP (remote desktop) is real time it does not lend itself to being proxied. Seehttps://www.strongvpn.com/difference_between_proxy_and_vpn.shtml

Comment: Sorry, but I fear you misunderstand.  @barlop comment is loosely speaking - except strictly speaking a VPN is not hosted it is "terminated".   Nevertheless a VPN service does not act as a "man in the middle which forwards the request" for you - it simply routes the packets in such a way that they appear to come from a different location.  A VPN server can be defined as a "virtual router", but not a proxy.  More links evidencing the difference - https://www.bestvpn.com/blog/4085/proxies-vs-vpn-whats-the-difference/  http://wiki.hidemyass.com/VPN